# Is there a difference between DB_DOUBLE and dbDouble?

Tags: ms-access, types, vba

I've just started a new work and I've got to manage, maintain (and feel sorry for) MS-Access databases and application.

I must normalize, then batch-copy a DB from the original files to the new model.  But when "Select Cas-ing" the read data-types, I'm offered two choices for each and every data-type; dbDouble and DB_DOUBLE, dbDecimal and DB_DECIMAL, etc.

Anyone knows why the two?

Thanks for feeding my curiosity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB_* are deprecated constants that are part of the Access object model and are provided only for backward compatibility. dbDouble and others are part of the DAO object model:

```
?Access.OldConstants.DB_DOUBLE
 7 
?DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbDouble
 7
```

I'm guessing that most (all?) constants will be the same, but you should confirm that yourself either via the Object Browser (<kbd>F2</kbd> in the IDE) or the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>).

In any case, I would stick with the DAO constants because the others are deprecated.